# Java HTML Apache Tomcat Embed JPanel or JFrame to HTML without New Open Windows

Tags: java, html, swing, apache, tomcat

I use tomcat to load my java library on my web page. There is a JPanel on my library. I can show it with JFrame on my website with new open java windows. Can I embed my JPanel (or JFrame) to my web page without opening a new java windows? (Without JApplet)

Comment: I'd suggest you first get an idea on what swing is opposed to what HTML does. I'm pretty sure that what you claim is possible with a JFrame just happens to work on the machine where the server runs...

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: Maybe (sort-of). Look into [GWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) or [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).